# What are some good tree suggestions for providing some shade for the house (Seattle, WA)?

Tags: trees, shade

There's been another question asked about [trees for shading a house](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-is-a-fast-growing-deciduous-tree-for-shading-house-in-summer-long-island), but I have some different criteria (plus a different climate).

I'm planning on landscaping an area that's next to my house that's currently a cement patio.  This patio, which is on the west side of the house, results in the house warming up quite a bit in late summer when the afternoon sun hits. So, my primary goal in landscaping is to add a few features that will minimize the heat in the summer.

I'm looking to plant one to three smaller trees, and am looking for suggestions.  Here's the criteria I'd like to match:

- Deciduous tree
- Height between 10 and 30 feet maximum
- Spread between 10 and 20 feet in diameter
- Provides at least some shade (e.g. not like that ginkgo tree I have in front)
- Roots aren't too aggressive (won't rob nearby plants of water or attack pipes)
- Does well in US pacific NW climate

Answer (score 6):

Below are some small trees that meet your specific criteria:

- [Amur Maackia *(Maackia amurensis)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maackia_amurensis)
- [Trident Maple *(Acer buergerianum)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_buergerianum)
- [Vine Maple *(Acer circinatum)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_circinatum)
- [Flame Amur Maple *(Acer ginnala 'Flame")*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_ginnala)
- [Paperbark Maple *(Acer griseum)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_griseum)
- [Japanese Maple *(Acer palmatum)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_palmatum)
- [Three-Flower Maple *(Acer triflorum)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acer_triflorum)
- [Paw Paw *(Asimina triloba)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asimina_triloba)
- [Japanese Hornbeam *(Carpinus japonica)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpinus_japonica)
- [Eastern Redbud *(Cercis canadensis)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercis_canadensis)
- [Judas Tree *(Cercis siliquastrum)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercis_siliquastrum)
- [Pagoda Dogwood *(Cornus alternifolia)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornus_alternifolia)
- [Kousa Dogwood *(Cornus kousa 'Chinensis')*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornus_kousa)
- [American Smoke Tree *(Cotinus obovatus)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotinus)
- [Tuscarora Hybrid Crape Myrtle *(Lagerstroemia 'tuscarora')*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagerstroemia)
- [Elizabeth Magnolia *(Magnolia 'Elizabeth')*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnolia)
- [Galaxy Magnolia *(Magnolia 'Galaxy')*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnolia)
- [Loebner Magnolia *(Magnolia x loebneri)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnolia)
- [Persian Parrotia *(Parrotia persica)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrotia_persica)
- [Mt. St. Helens Plum *(Prunus 'Frankthrees')*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus)
- [Newport Plum *(Prunus 'Newport')*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus)
- [Snow Goose Cherry *(Prunus 'Snowgoose')*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus)
- [Thundercloud Plum *(Prunus cerasifera 'Thundercloud')*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_plum)
- [Akebono Flowering Cherry *(Prunus x yedoensis 'Akebono')*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prunus_x_yedoensis)
- [Orange Bark Stewartia *(Stewartia monodelpha)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewartia)
- [Japanese Stewartia *(Stewartia psuedocamellia)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewartia_pseudocamellia)
- [Fragrant Styrax *(Styrax obassia)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Styrax_obassia)

The above list of small trees comes from, [Recommended - Small Tree List](http://www.seattle.gov/transportation/treeplanting.htm#recommend), via Seattle Department of Transportation - Street Tree Planting Procedures.

Direct link to PDF: [Small Tree List](http://www.seattle.gov/transportation/docs/uf/Small_Street_Tree_List.pdf)

You may also wish to try the below options for further small tree recommendations that meet your specific criteria and some useful tree related information to aid you make the right decisions:

- [Small Trees - Great Plant Picks](http://www.greatplantpicks.org/search?searchterm=small%20tree&searchtype=category&title=%27Small%20Trees%27) (is an educational plant awards program of outstanding plants for the maritime Pacific Northwest)
- [Native Plant Guide - Information and Services for King County, Washington](http://green.kingcounty.gov/gonative/Plant.aspx?Act=search)
- [SelecTree from Urban Forest Ecosystems Institute](http://selectree.calpoly.edu/)
- [Washington Park Arboretum - UW Botanic Gardens](http://depts.washington.edu/uwbg/gardens/wpa.shtml)
- [Linda K Chalker-Scott from Washington State University Extension.](https://cahnrsdb.wsu.edu/directory/individualDisplay.aspx?personID=1882) **Note:** I have sent Linda an email, asking her for small tree recommendations that meet your specific criteria, if I receive a reply I will update this post appropriately.
- [Tree Placement on Home Grounds](http://extension.missouri.edu/p/G6900)

Comment: Wow!  I am definitely going to have to bookmark your answer.  This is going to be a source of resources for some time to come.